# How to order ascending by highest price using React?

Tags: reactjs

I have a component that receives offers and want to set the highest on top. This is the code:

```
var Offerslist = React.createClass({
  _renderOffers: function(key) {
    var details = this.props[key];

    // TODO: set order of highest offer descending

    return (
      <li key={key} className="offer-of-item">
        &euro; {details.price}
        <a className="remove-offer" onClick={this._removeOffer}>X</a>
      </li>
    )
  },
  render : function() {
    return (
      <ol className="list-of-offers-per-item">
        {Object.keys(this.props).map(this._renderOffers)}
      </ol>
    )
  }
});
```

I thought of populating an array with objects {price:123, offerid:'foo123'} and then use .sort by price. But I can't populate an array like this as it never iterates through all objects at once. Is there perhaps some built-in React way to do this?

data:
[image: data]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a ordinary array you'd use the `sort` method. But since your `offers` is an object, not an array, you can sort the `keys` by looking up the price in the `offers` object like this:

```
Object.keys(this.props)
   .sort((a, b) => ( this.props[a].price - this.props[b].price ))
   .map( this._renderOffers)
```